# Removing the bibliography name

Tags: bibliographies, babel

I use the »[babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)« package with option `bahasa` . For bibliography purposes, I make the section "Daftar Pustaka", but `thebibliography` environment produced "Pustaka". So there are two titles. How to remove the `thebibliography` name?

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: \documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=10pt]{article}

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The options you use for your document class are not valid for the standard `article` class, but for the corresponding `scrartcl` class from »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)«.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply renew `\refname`, which determines the bibliography heading.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\addto{\captionsbahasa}{%
  \renewcommand*{\refname}{Daftar Pustaka}
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{key} Bibliography item
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**
Correspondingly to the comment, the heading of the references is now a numbered section with an entry in the ToC.

Comment: I mean to removing thebibliographyname.

Comment: Thanks, answered! as in: \addto{\captionsbahasa}{%
  \renewcommand*{\refname}{}
}

Comment: @kalakay: Why do you want to remove it? Do you need a numbered bibliography section with an entry in the ToC?

Comment: Yes, you are right, and now has been answered thanks to your help.

Comment: @kalakay: Then you are probably interested in the update of my example.